# how we can show rain emoji animation on backgroud in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

like this-https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g2M52ZVFb0cnN8DoARwkAbB9yJiWkCh5/view?usp=share_link

please tell how we  can show animation      on background in flutter ,

Comment: try adding link like it is. now for ur U gotta do it manually, try Animated Position widget inside of the for loop

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I hope this can help you.

try using `animated_background` package and customize with rain behavior

Thank you.